# How to set default height value of sliverappbar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar

As you might know, if we want to decrease the height of appbar, we need to wrap Appbar with preferredSize widget.

But in the case of SilverAppbar, preferredSize widget does not work to decrease the height of default size of SilverAppber height.

How can I decrease the height of default SilverAppbar?

*plz note that I am talking about the default size of height of SilverAppbar, not about expanded height size of it.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52933076/minimum-height-in-sliverappbar-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52933076/minimum-height-in-sliverappbar-flutter)

Comment: You can inherit or even copy SilverAppbar and modify it to do what you want currently. I hope the flutter team will fix it soon.